# XML Attribute Validation from Enumeration List

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I have an XML, where I need to verify attribute values with a Enumeration type in Schema using XSD.

**Sample XML:**

```
<Test StatusValue="X R,Y">
    <TestXSD>TestXSD</TestXSD>
    <xsd>xsd</xsd>
</Test>
```

Above I need to verify attribute values X and Y are part of my Enumeration list of schema.

Enumeration List in Schema as below

```
   <xs:simpleType name="StatusGroup">
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="X R"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="Y"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="Z"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="B"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="E"/>
     </xs:restriction>  
 </xs:simpleType>
```

I am not able to validate values because of comma separation between the two values. `X, Y`

Comment: What is the problem, more precisely?

Comment: As my attribute value is separated with , I'm unable to validate with enumlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

OP says that he can't change the xml and xsd, so we move to the solution by `XMLAdapter` of JAXB:

```
public class Test {
  @XmlElement(name = "StatusValue")
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StatusValueAdapter.class)
  public List<StatusGroup> getStatusValues(){}
}

public class StatusValueAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, List<StatusGroup>> {
  public List<StatusGroup> unmarshal(String content) throws Exception {
    // content = "X R,Y"
    final String[] split = content.split(",");
    // validate here against your enum
  }
}

@XmlEnum 
public enum StatusGroup {}
```

More:

- [validate and parse xml in Java -- start up](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/01/validate-and-parse-xml-in-java.html)
- [xsd tutorial on my blog](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/01/xsd-tutorial.html)
- [jaxb problem list on my blog](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/01/jaxb-problem-list.html)

---

You can define you `StatusValue` as following:

```
<xs:complexType name="Test">
    ...
    <xs:attribute name="StatusValue" type="StatusList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="StatusList">
    <xs:list itemType="StatusGroup"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

then you can verify it easily by jaxb (notice the seperator of list is space):

```
<Test StatusValue="X Y">
    <TestXSD>TestXSD</TestXSD>
    <xsd>xsd</xsd>
</Test>
```

Comment: For my Attributes value delimiter is ','(Comma) so I couldn't able to validate above scenario

Comment: @Kumar_diru Can't you change the xsd definition and xml? If you can't, I may update my answer.

Comment: No I cant delete XSD and XML, To be more specific I have updated the XML and XSD enum values

Comment: I have no idea about jaxb, cant we achieve same by XSD?

Comment: @Kumar_diru But xsd just define the schema, you have to use some lib/framework to validate xml with the help of xsd. You can't just use xsd to validate xml.

Comment: We are giving this specific Schema to users to create an Input xml for one of our application, were users will use our schema to built an XML . 
How we can express this delimiter ',' through XSD in attribute

Comment: @Kumar_diru If your 'build' means writing xml through editor, you can't force it. Some IDE will provide validation functionality, and some reminder of what to write in some place, but even in idea, it doesn't always work. So you have to validate then parse xml by yourself, I have updated my answer adding a tutorial about the sartup of JAXB to validate and parse xml.